# Android: How can I find out that a user is trying to access the network?

Tags: android, networking, connectivity

How can I find out with Android API that a user is trying to access the network in android?

I can check through ConnectivityManager if the device has [or not] access to networking
but I wonder is there a Broadcast to receive or some other way?

I want to be informed that a user tries to access a network transaction either when network is available (3G data or WiFi) or not in that exact moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have

```
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION  broadcast action in WifiManager class.
```

or go through below link

```
http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. Again, I would like to find out if possible, that a user is trying to access the network at the very exact moment. ie. There is no connectivity and the users opens the Browser to browse on the web.